# jquery mobile with once-shown splash page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a design that build a splash page (may with loading icon so "start screen" of iOS is not satisfied) on jQuery Mobile webapp. However I have this page-proceess problem now: The page after splash page is a function list. When user tap one function it will enter one specific function page. The specific page has not 'back' button on page, so user has to press "back" button on browser in order to go back to function list (and then press "forward" to return to specific page). **Function list page must not go back to splash page by "back" button on browser.**

```
 --------   Auto    ---------------   User Tap    -------------------
| Splash | ------> | Function List | ----------> | Specific Function |
 --------           ---------------               -------------------
    ^                     |  ^                                ^
    |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  |________________________________|
         CAN NOT BACK         Back & Forward Button of Browser
```

Here is what I tried:

1. To begin with, if I do normally with blank hash for splash and another 2 hashed for 2 other pages, lish page has "Back" button enabled and user can tap it to go back to splash page.
2. If I use `changeHash: false` from splash to list, when user press "back" button on list, it will go back to splash page but not list page.
3. If I use `$('#splash-page').remove()` when list page is shown, when user press "back" button on list, system will re-generate splash page and it will also go back to splash page but not list page.
4. If I use `hashListeningEnabled = false` on mobileinit and change it to true when list is shown, it doesn't work. Configure setting may only enabled on mobileinit.
5. One possible solution is use `location.replace('#page-list')` method. But it cannot set the transition from splash to list. Setting `defaultPageTransition` can helps but I has another default transition wanted, set `defaultPageTransition` face to one specific transition and other transitions in code need lots of work. `defaultPageTransition` can set only once from tries 4.

So I need a solution without some hacks like tries 5.
Thank you for reading till here.

---

In addition, My android 2.3 device can not support `location.replace`, even change `location.hash` can not be listenned by jQuery Mobile.